# r ggplot - change x-axis tick labels without losing geom_smooth stats

Tags: r, ggplot2

I make a scatter plot and fit a line on it; now I need to change the tick-level labels of my x-axis, which is continuous. The data:

```
y <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 5:9)
> y
  a b
1 1 5
2 2 6
3 3 7
4 4 8
5 5 9
```

And I plot it:

```
   ggplot(y, aes(a, b))+
      geom_jitter()+
      stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal)+
      geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y~x)
```

[image]

This is not bad, but I need to change the labels at the x-axis tick level, to make them meaningful, so I try with this:

```
ggplot(y, aes(a, b))+
  geom_jitter()+
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal)+
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y~x)+
  scale_x_discrete("A_Variable", c("a","b","c","d","f"))
```

[image]

It doesn't work. I learn from another SO question that I need to change the x variable to factor, but when I do this, I lose my `geom_smooth` line. How do I change the tick-level labels of my x-axis without losing my `geom_smooth` stats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the [`scale_x_continuous`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html), since your `a` is a continuous variable. In order to define names for the `breaks`, you can use the `labels` parameter.

```
data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 5:9) %>%
    ggplot(aes(a, b))+
    geom_jitter()+
    stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal)+
    geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y~x)+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:5, labels=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "f")) +
    labs(x="A_Variable", y="B_Variable", title="A plot")
```

[image]